# WIn764b: Cannot open include file: 'winsock2.h': No such file or directory when running npm install -g karma

Tags: visual-studio, npm, winapi, karma-runner

I'm trying to install karma on Windows7 64 bit.  When I run

```
npm install -g karma
```

I get the following error:

```
...\.node-gyp\0.8.22\deps\uv\include\ares.h(49): fatal error C1
083: Cannot open include file: 'winsock2.h': No such file or directory [C:\User
...\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\karma\node_modules\socket.io\node
_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\ws\build\bufferutil.vcxproj]
```

I downloaded and installed the 2.0 sdk which the installer needed but still have this issue.  I suspect this is a class path issue but setting the path didn't solve it.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

binding.sln was built with Visual Studio 2010.  I decided to install Visual Studio 2010.  I selected "Or, download the previous: Visual C++ 2010 Express." from http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/products/visual-studio-2010-express and npm install -g karma ran without errors.